# Finding the extrema of $y=2\sin 2x + \sin 4x$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

> Determine the minimum and maximum points of $y=2\sin 2x + \sin 4x$.

I've worked out the first and second derivative:

$y'=8\cos x \cos 3x$, $y''=-8(\sin x \cos 3x+3\sin3x\cos x)$

and the critical points: $x_1=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $x_2=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{3}k\pi$.

But how do I find the extremas now? Since the function is periodic, how am I supposed to test the second derivative for all critical points?

Comment: Can you write e.g. $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2} + k \pi)$ in terms of $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: By function transformations, you can find the extrema of $g(x) = 2 \sin x + \sin 2x$ and then compress $g(x)$ by a factor of $2$ to find the extrema of the original function.

Answer (score 1):

In the function $$f(x)=2 \sin 2x + \sin 4x$$ whose period is $\pi$, we can start by considering the values in the interval $0\leq x \leq\pi$.

You already obtained that, in this range, the first derivative

$$f'(x)=4(\cos 2x + \cos 4x)\\=
8\cos x \cos 3x$$

is zero for $x=\pi/6$, $x=\pi/2$ and $x=5\pi/6$.

Among these values, only the first and the last one are extrema, as for $x=\pi/2$ the second derivative

$$f''(x)=-8 (\sin x \cos 3x + 3\, \sin 3x \cos x)$$

is zero. In particular, since we have $$f''(x)=-12\sqrt{3}\,\, \text{  for } x=\pi/6$$
$$f''(x)=12\sqrt{3}\,\, \text{  for } x=5\pi/6$$

then $x=\pi/6$ is a local maximum and $x=5\pi/6$ is a local minimum.

Now we can generalize to the whole function. Since $f(x)$ has period $\pi$, the whole sets of $x$ values corresponding to the extrema are given by
$$x_{max}=\frac{\pi}{6}+n\pi$$
$$x_{min}=\frac{5\pi}{6}+n\pi$$

It is quite straightforward to note that the values of $\sin 2x$ and $\sin 4x$, which are present in $f(x)$, are equal for all values of
$x_{max}$, irrespective of $n$. The same holds for $x_{min}$. So the maximum and minimum in the range $0\leq x \leq \pi$ are the extrema of the whole function.

Substituting $x=\pi/6$ and $x=5\pi/6$  in $f(x)$  we have

$$\max[f(x)]= 2 \sin \frac \pi3 + \sin \frac{ 2\pi}{3}\\=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}
{2}$$

and

$$\min[f(x)]= 2 \sin \frac {5\pi}{3} + \sin \frac{ 10\pi}{3}\\=-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}
{2}$$

Here is a plot of the function, showing the maxima for $x=\pi/6+n\pi$ and the minima for
$x=5\pi/6+n\pi$.

[image]

Comment: Wait but how do we know the period of the function is $\pi$?

Comment: Since $\sin x$ has period $2\pi$, then $\sin 2x$ has period $\pi$ and $\sin 4x$ has period $\pi/2$. When we sum two periodic functions with periods $p_1$ and $p_2$, if there are positive integers $j$ and $k$ such that $jp_1=kp_2=P$, then $P$ is the period of their sum. In our case, we directly get that the period is $\pi$. Also note that, in general, the sum of periodic functions is not necessarily periodic.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=2\sin2x(1+\cos2x)=8\sin x\cos^3x$$

Case $\#1:$ If $\sin x,\cos x\ge0$

$$\dfrac{a\dfrac{\sin^2x}a+b\dfrac{\cos^2x}b}{a+b}\ge\sqrt[a+b]{(\sin^2x/a)^a(\cos^2x/b)^b}$$

Make $\dfrac{2a}{a+b}=k,\dfrac{2b}{a+b}=3k$

On division, $b=3a\implies k=?$

Case $\#2:$

If $\sin x,\cos x<0;$ set $x=\pi+y$

Case $\#3:$

If $\sin x\ge0,\cos x\le0;$ set $x=\pi-y$

Case $\#4:$

If $\sin x\le0,\cos x\ge0:$ set $x=-y$

Comment: This has just confused me even more...

Comment: @downmath,  I have used https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/AM-GM_Inequality#Weighted_AM-GM_Inequality